# ERD & SQL for a database that collects information that changes over time while keeping the old information?

Tags: database-design, relational-database, erd

Fields will be updated but the previous information needs to be kept in the database so I can scroll through the previous information as well as the current.

How do I make an ERD for that?

How do I do it with MySQL?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Temporal_database

Comment: Ask 1 specific researched non-duplicate question. Please before considering posting: Pin down code issues via [mre]. Read manuals/references & google error messages & many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular names/strings/numbers, 'site:stackoverflow.com' & tags; read many answers. SO/SE search is poor & literal & unusual, read the help. Google re googling/searching, including Q&A at [meta] & [meta.se]. [How much research effort is expected?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/3404097) [ask] [Help] Reflect research in posts.

Answer (score 0):

The problem that you want to address is called ***data versioning***, i.e. keeping  track of all the successive changes of the data (*Caution: not be confused with [database versioning](https://weaintplastic.github.io/web-development-field-guide/Collaboration/Database_Versioning/The_Concept_of_Database_Versioning), which is about managing different versions of the database structure/scheme*).

There are many designs possible to address this, depending on what you want to achieve and if you make a difference between accessing the the latest version and the previous versions. A very few examples:

- One approach is to add a validity timestamp (begin date and end date) to each to the tables you want to "historize". The current version would have no end date, until a newer version is created.  But as you can imagine,  this is not without consequence for the primary key (which would have to include the version discriminator, i.e. begin date, which would require to include it also to foreign keys that refer to it and keep all this in sync). This is to be used when you need particular care for versioning also the relation (since new version would require to change the related tows in other tables, i.e. creating also newer versions there).
- Another approach is to use this approach, but add for every these table a master table with only the primary key, and the version id (begin date) of the currently valid row for this primary key.  This would facilitate retrieving the last version, and still keep the foreign keys in the original tables unchanged. This works only if the primary key will never change, but makes the relations easier to manage.  The overall consistency (i.e. relating different objects in previous states) requires to use the timestamp as version id, and needs some additional work to relate the right versions.
- Yet another approach is to keep in your tables only the latest version,  and make for each table a history table: Every time a change is made, you update the table as usual and you insert the new version in the history table (updating the end validity of the previous version).  This approach is practical when most of the time you work with the current version and only exceptionally browse through the past versions.
- Instead of start and end dates you could also use version identifiers (incremented integer, starting at 1 when a row is inserted, and incremented at each insertion) with or without an `active` flag.  However, this is often more complicated to use if there are many related tables.

For the ERD, there is no surprise:  enrich your current diagram with the additional entities(tables) and attributes(fields) as explained above. But usually, historization make diagrams much more difficult to read.

Answer (score -1):

From https://dev.to/zhiyueyi/design-a-table-to-keep-historical-changes-in-database-10fn,
solution #2, Use a History Table, is appropriate as the information won't be updated frequently, if ever.